# Disable Auto Numbering in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: sql, performance, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am doing performance tuning on a company product that relatest to putting a lot of financial data in to CRM. There seems to be a bottleneck at the point of Invoice creation where the following query is run

```
(@orgid uniqueidentifier)declare @currentval int 
update OrganizationBase 
set @currentval = CurrentInvoiceNumber, CurrentInvoiceNumber = CurrentInvoiceNumber + 1 
where OrganizationId = @orgid 
select @currentval
```

Despite running all of the code in a multi-threaded way, everything inevitably queues behind this task which for some reason seems to take a second or so to run.

I can't find any way to disable this auto-numbering as I would prefer to generate the invoice number myself for performance purposes (contiguous numbers are not a necessity).

So my questions are:

Q: Can auto numbering for invoices be turned off.
Q: Which out of the box plugin or workflow actually calls this data (it doesn't seem to be a stored proc)
Q: Is there another workaround that I am not considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable the autonumbering of the invoice, but CRM allows to set  a custom value as invoice number (invoicenumber field) when you create a new record, you can check the performance when you set manually the value

Comment: Simple but effective. If I manually provide the number then it seems to avoid updating the organisation base table. The only downside is that this won't work in future cases where contiguous numbering is needed but good enough for now, thanks.